# How to change a component config dynamically in Sencha?

Tags: extjs, config, sencha-architect

I have a datepicker and a combobox, when I select a value from the combobox, I want the datepicker config "format" change to the selected value, and display corresponding to the selected format. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `Ext.apply` :

```
Ext.apply(datepicker, {format: 'LanguageValue'});
```

This will apply the 'LanguageValue' to the **format** config of the **datepicker** component.